# t.test outputs in the `table` package in R

Tags: r, list

So here's a sample of the data I am working with:

```
> dput(candidateEvokeDFYoung)
structure(list(youngTreatment = structure(c(NA, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candTrustworthy = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candKnowledgeable = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candQualified = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candConservative = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candLiberal = structure(c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), candInexperienced = structure(c(0, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candPrincipled = structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candDistance = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    candEfficacy = structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), format.stata = "%10.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I am trying to do is generate a table using the tables package with results from a t.test. The trouble I am having is I've taken this dataset and have used lapply to calculate my t.tests on each of the variables with youngTreatment as my 'y' variable:

```
    candidateEvokesDiffYoung = lapply(candidateEvokeDFYoung[-1], function(x) t.test(x ~ candidateEvokeDFYoung$youngTreatment))
```

This gives me a list of lists. I have no clue how to use tables::tabular to access

```
    list[['statistic']]
```

and

```
    list[['p.value]]
```

I could definitely just manually pull all of these out myself and put it in a dataframe for stargazer or something, but I was wondering if there was someone who knew how I could do this more efficiently and with the tables package.

Answer (score 0):

`t.test` returns objects of the class `htest`. I believe the best way to gather the results of an object of the class `htest` is to use the function `tidy` of the package `broom`.

```
library(broom)
candidateEvokesDiffYoung = lapply(candidateEvokeDFYoung[-1], 
                           function(x) {
                                   t.test(x ~ candidateEvokeDFYoung$youngTreatment)
})
m <- t(sapply(candidateEvokesDiffYoung, tidy))
```

This will allow you to refer to the elements in a similar way to what you seem to be trying to.

```
> m["candTrustworthy",  "p.value"][[1]]
[1] 0.7875872

> unlist(m[,  "p.value"])
candTrustworthy candKnowledgeable     candQualified  candConservative       candLiberal candInexperienced    candPrincipled      candDistance      candEfficacy                                                                                         
0.7875872         0.7875872            0.7875872         0.3632175           0.3465935         0.6933006         0.3790778               NaN         0.3632175
```